# Document linked as column reference in list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a document library with 3 key values: "Company", "Audit", "Task".
I have a separate list with rows as "Audit" and "Task", and columns as "company".

the data set looks like this:

"Pre-audit" "Tax calc." "Company1" "company2"...

"Pre-audit" " deferred tax" "Company1" "Company2"...

...

"FYE" "Tax calc." "Company1" "Company2"...

What I need to do is when a document is dropped in the doc library and given values for company audit and task, to automatically link to the list or create a record and link if the row does not exist yet.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow that will create a list item in a list when a document is uploaded to the library.  Put all the column values into variables, and use the variables to create the new list item.  Updating an existing list item is a little more complicated, but as long as you have some piece of uniquely identifiable information you should be able to find the existing list item and update a field in the item with a workflow.